# Herokuでnode.jsで作ったアプリを公開できない

Tags: node.js, heroku

[node.jsで作ったアプリをHerokuで公開する！！](https://byuzensen.com/node-js-express-app-heroku)

上記の記事に沿って node.jsで作ったアプリをHerokuで公開しようとしているのですが、無事公開できたか確認するために、コマンドプロンプトに
`heroku open`
と打つと、

```
Error: Missing reqired flag:
   -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 See more help with --help
```

と返ってきます。
Herokuの管理画面上から「Open App」を押しても駄目でした。

因みにその1つ前の工程(ディレクトリのファイルをプッシュする所)で
`git push heroku master`
と打ち込んだ時に

```
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 Please make sure ou have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
```

と表示されたのですが、これは関係あるのでしょうか？

スペルミスはチェックしたけれども合っていました。
 何が駄目なんでしょうか？

windows10
 node.js バージョン10.15.3

Answer (score 0):

```
git push heroku master
```

↑このコマンドが失敗しているのは、gitのリモートレポジトリにherokuが登録されていないからです。
試しにコマンドプロンプトで`git remote`と打ち込んでみてください。
表示されるレポジトリ名に（あるいは何も表示されないかも）herokuが無いと思います。

参考にされているサイトの次のコマンドは正常に終了しましたか？

```
heroku git:clone -a アプリ名
```

おそらくgitやheroku、あるいはプログラミング自体も初心者の方なのかなとお見受けしました。
この場で一つ一つ問題を潰していくのは、やり取りが煩雑になり過ぎて難しいと思うので
もう一度最初から手順通りにやってみることをおすすめします。
他のサイトを参考にするのもおすすめです。